# CarbonServerManager Carbon initialization is delayed due to the following unsatisfied items

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Hi I am doing following steps from http://wso2.com/library/articles/2014/02/cloud-to-rdbms-using-wso2-esb/

the following issue happens after installation of **Data Service Hosting 4.2.0**  and restarted the ESB.

```
[2017-03-15 11:58:30,385]  WARN - CarbonServerManager Carbon initialization is delayed due to the following unsatisfied items:
[2017-03-15 11:58:30,385]  WARN - CarbonServerManager Waiting for required OSGiAxis2Service: org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.task-4.4.0
```

how can I fix or revert it.

Answer (score 0):

What is the ESB version you are using?

If you want to revert you can select it from installed features list and click uninstall

Comment: I wasn't able to reach the admin panel because Carbon UI not started yet.
I have ESB 5.0.0, issue solved just restart server with graceful mode. Issue happens when I have restart server with forcely restart after the  **Data Service Hosting 4.2.0**